# Часы отрисованные canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Подскажите как отрисовать циферблат для часов используя canvas. Знаю, что можно прописывать координаты вручную, но это геморрой, хотел попробовать написать функцию, которая сама будет рассчитывать градусы, и рисовать круг с цифрой. Должно было получится вот так:
[image: Циферблат]

Но столкнулся с проблемой, что не понимаю как и откуда отсчитывать 30 градусов и там рисовать круг, потом вставлять туда число. Может у вас будут идее которые помогут направить меня в правильно русло?

```js
window.onload = function () {
            var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('clock');
            if (drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
                var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
                // Окружность 
                context.strokeStyle = "#000";
                context.fillStyle = "#fff";
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
                context.fill();
                // задаем местоположение
                context.fillStyle = "#fff";
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(150, 70, 16, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
                context.fill();

                var Ygol = 30;
                with (Math) {
                    n = sin(Ygol * PI / 180);
                    context.fillStyle = "red";
                    context.beginPath();
                    // context.arc(116, 90, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.stroke();
                    context.fill();
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="clock" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Возможно, это бред. определённо проще будет, если это все прописать css+ js. Но тогда я всё равно туплю над этим алгоритмом с прорисовкой, этих кругов с цифрами.

Comment: Тригонометрия в помощь: https://toster.ru/q/18976#answer_77508

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот Вам часики на канве нарисовал =)

все координаты рассчитываются в этом методе:

`current` - текущее значение

`total` - размер шкалы

`radius` - это расстояние от центра, как это ни странно

```
function xy(current, total, radius) {
  let angle = 2 * Math.PI / total * current - Math.PI/2;
  return [
    Math.cos(angle) * radius, 
    Math.sin(angle) * radius
  ];
}
```

```js
let center = 150;

window.onload = function () {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('clock');
    let ctx = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"; 
    
    draw();

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        circle(ctx, [0, 0], 140); // внешний круг
        Array(12).fill(0).map((e, i) => { // 12 делений
          let c = xy(i, 12, 111); 
          circle(ctx, c, 22);
          ctx.strokeText(i||12, center + c[0], center + c[1]+2);
        }); 
        let d = new Date();
        let sec = d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds()/1000;
        let min = d.getMinutes() + sec/60;
        let hour = d.getHours() + min/60;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2.0; 
        line(ctx, xy(sec, 60, 77)); // секундная стрелка
        ctx.lineWidth = 3.0;
        line(ctx, xy(min, 60, 66)); // минутная стрелка
        ctx.lineWidth = 4.0;
        line(ctx, xy(hour, 12, 55)); // часовая стрелка
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    } 
}

function circle(ctx, xy, r) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(center + xy[0], center + xy[1]);
  ctx.arc(0, 0, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function line(ctx, xy) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.lineTo(center + xy[0], center + xy[1]);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

// положение на окружности
function xy(current, total, radius) {
  let angle = 2 * Math.PI / total * current - Math.PI/2;
  return [
    Math.cos(angle) * radius, 
    Math.sin(angle) * radius
  ];
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: а пояснения где?:)

Comment: @Grundy боюсь представить что тут объяснять надо

Answer (score 5):

В качестве бонуса версия на `svg`+`d3.js`

```js
let center = 150;

let svg = d3.select('#clock');

let hours = svg.selectAll('circle.hour')
   .data(d3.range(12).map(i => xy(i, 12)))
   .enter()
   .append('g')
   .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d[0]*120}, ${d[1]*120})`);
   
hours.append('circle')
   .classed('hour', true)
   .attr('r', 22);
   
hours.append('text')
   .html((d,i) => i+1);   

let secLine = svg.append('path');
let minLine = svg.append('path');
let hourLine = svg.append('path');

draw();

function draw(){
    let d = new Date();
    let sec = d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds()/1000;
    let min = d.getMinutes() + sec/60;
    let hour = d.getHours() + min/60;
    arrow(secLine, xy(sec, 60), 77);
    arrow(minLine, xy(min, 60), 66);
    arrow(hourLine, xy(hour, 12), 55);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function arrow(line, data, len) {
  line.datum(data).attr('d', d => `
    M${d[0]*20},${d[1]*20} 
    L${d[0]*len},${d[1]*len}
  `)
}    
   
function xy(current, total) {
  let angle = 2 * Math.PI / total * current - Math.PI/2;
  return [Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle)];
}
```

```css
path, circle {
  stroke-width:1.8;
  fill:none;
  stroke: black;
}

text {
  text-anchor:middle;
  alignment-baseline:middle;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:monospace
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="clock" width="400" height="400" viewbox="-200 -200 400 400">
<circle r=150></circle>
<circle r=15></circle>
</svg>
```

Точки считаю той же функцией:

```
function xy(current, total) {
  let angle = 2 * Math.PI / total * current - Math.PI/2;
  return [Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle)];
}
```

хотя можно было обойтись только поворотами директивами самого `svg`

```js
d3.select('svg')
   .selectAll('g')
   .data(d3.range(12))
   .enter().append('g')
   .attr('transform', d => `rotate(${360/12*d})`)
   .html(d => `<circle r="20" cy="-120"></circle>
               <text y="-118">${d||12}</text>`);
draw();   

function draw(){
    let d = new Date();
    let sec = d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds()/1000;
    let min = d.getMinutes() + sec/60;
    let hour = d.getHours() + min/60;
  
    arr('#hour', 12, hour);
    arr('#min', 60, min);
    arr('#sec', 60, sec);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function arr(selector, total, current){
  d3.select(selector).attr('transform', `rotate(${360/total*current})`)
}
```

```css
path, circle {
  stroke-width: 1.8;
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-200 -200 400 400">
  <circle r="150"></circle>
  <circle r="20"></circle>
  <path id="hour" d="M0,-25 L0,-40"></path>
  <path id="min"  d="M0,-25 L0,-60"></path>
  <path id="sec"  d="M0,-25 L0,-80"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хороший, полезный ответ